# Добавить кнопку перехода на другую страницу в РНР

Tags: php

Хочу добавить кнопку для перехода на другую страницу, использовал способы:

экранируеться сама ссылка

```
echo '<button id="button-list" onclick="window.location='http://172.19.0.2/admin'"class="button-on-form">Order list</button>';
```

Если изменить символы на `" "` - создаёться кнопка, но она не работает:

```
 echo "<button id="button-list" onclick="window.location='http://172.19.0.2/admin'"class="button-on-form">Order list</button>";
```

и так тоже:

```
   echo  '<button id="button-list" onclick="window.location="http://172.19.0.2/admin" "class="button-on-form">Order list</button>';
```

Очевидно, что я что-то делают не так, но в чём проблема?
Спасибо

Comment: `echo '<button id="button-list" onclick="window.location=\'http://172.19.0.2/admin\'" class="button-on-form">Order list</button>';`

Comment: @Эдуард, понял, экранировать символы. Добавте как ответ, что бы я мог Вас отметить) Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте обратный слеш для экранирования необходимых символов:

```
echo '<button id="button-list" onclick="window.location=\'http://172.19.0.2/admin\'" class="button-on-form">Order list</button>';
```